# wordpress if not index echo something else

Tags: php, wordpress

I'd like to give my title `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>` conditional statement. If not HOMEPAGE just display whatever it is = `<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>`. if HOMEPAGE display `THIS IS + <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>`

so the syntax should be

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$page = basename($path);
$page = basename($path, '.php');

?>


<?php if($page == 'index') 
  {echo 'This is'. get_the_title();  }
   else 
   {echo get_the_title();}
?>
```

the problem is I dont really know in wordpress do we use the same way or something smarter or easier.

OH, FORGOT! 
**Actually, my index/homepage is not real index, it is the page called "HOMEPAGE "
setting from `Reading Settings -> a static page, front page => HOMEPAGE`**

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place your code in `functions.php`

```
function title_edit($title){
    if(!is_front_page() || get_post_type() != 'page') return $title;
    $title = 'Home: '.$title;
    return $title;
}

add_filter('the_title','title_edit');
```

Comment: thank you :-) is that possible to place this code in `/theme/functinos.php` ? however I got error message says` Cannot redeclare get_the_title() (previously declared in \wordpress\wp-includes\post-template.php:102)`

Comment: just change the name or apply a hook.

Comment: Actually, my index/homepage is not real index, it is the page called "HOMEPAGE " setting from `Reading Settings -> a static page, front page => HOMEPAGE`, is_home is not working for this case. Thanks a lot

Comment: thanks for that, got error ` Missing argument 1 for title_edit()`

Comment: finally i made it works also. I didn't tried to edit core theme file. but congrats to solve it yourself. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks @silentboy

```
<?php if(is_front_page()) 
    echo 'This is'.get_the_title(); 
     else echo get_the_title(); ?>
```